# MySQL. Как удалить большое количество (56тыс) строк из таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста насколько возможно быстрый способ удалить 56тыс строк из таблицы по условию?

```
DELETE FROM b_iblock_section WHERE IBLOCK_ID=4 LIMIT 100
```

пытался так для начала на 100 строках потренироваться, но получаю ошибку

> #1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Как нибудь можно ее обойти и успешно удалить? Спасибо заранее

Comment: У меня ощущение, что что то другое держит блокорвку на таблицу и вы поэтому не можете из нее удалять. Потому что 100 строк вообще должны удалится за доли секунды

Comment: Впрочем и 56тыс строк это не показатель, здесь важнее сам размер таблицы. Поддерживаю по поводу блокировки

Comment: А как же узнать что держит? И какая есть панацея чтобы не блокировалось?